# Matrix that are skew symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $A, \tilde{A}$ are $n\times n$ real matrices. How do you show if $(Ax,x)=(\tilde{A}x,x)$, then $A-\tilde{A}$ is skew-symmetric?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's equal to $\langle (A-\tilde{A})x,x \rangle=0$ , which it is also equal to $\langle (A-\tilde{A}),x x^T\rangle=0$, now assume $x=e_i$, then if we put $B=A-\tilde{A}$, then we have $B_{ii}=0$. Now assume $x=e_{ij}$ is a vector with two ones on $i$th and $j$th position, then $B_{ii}+B_{ij}+B_{jj}+B_{ji}=0$. Since $B_{ii}=B_{jj}=0$, it's equal to $B_{ij}+B_{ji}=0$ and it's $B_{ij}=-B_{ji}$. This is the definition of skew-symmetric.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer。 I apprreciated

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is skew-symmetric [if and only if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Properties) $(x, Ax) = 0$ for every $x$.

Using the fact that the scalar product is linear, you easily get

$$((A-\tilde A)x, x) = 0$$ for every $x$, so $A-\tilde A$ is skew symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

You have for all $x$

$$0 \equiv (Ax,x)-(\tilde{A}x,x)=(Ax-\tilde{A}x,x)=((A-\tilde{A})x,x)=x^T(A-\tilde{A})x.$$

Let $B:=A-\tilde{A}$. [Differentiating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-vector_identities) the last equation gives

$$x^T(B+B^T) \equiv 0 $$

so that $B+B^T$ has to be the zero matrix, or $B^T=-B$.